React Bootstrap v2.10.4 Modal Close Button 'X' is not displaying
I have upgraded from react bootstrap 1 to 2. After upgrading close icon X is not showing in Modal header. Its closing the Modal on click but icon is not showing.
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                            <div className="alert_big"></div>
                            <span>Alert!</span>
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>

I tried passing closeLabel and closeVariant
